# Anything Slider not playing video on second loop in IE9

Tags: javascript, html5-video, anythingslider

I am using Anything slider in infinite slides with an HTML 5 video in one slide. The goal is to have the video run each time the slide loops. the problem is in IE9 it seems to break the slider on the second loop. The video does not play nor does it advance to the next slide, it just freezes.

```
onSlideInit: function (e, slider) {
                var vid = slider.$lastPage.find('video');
                if (vid.length && typeof (vid[0].pause) !== 'undefined') {
                    vid[0].pause();
                }

            },
            onSlideBegin: function (e, slider) { },
            onSlideComplete: function (slider) {
                // make current slide conform to user define data-duration value
                var video = slider.$lastPage.find('video');
                console.log(video)
                if (video.length > 0) {
                    video[0].currentTime = 0;
                }
                if (hasVideoSupport == "false") {
                    jwplayer("container").setup({
                        file: video,
                        flashplayer: "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
                        height: 400,
                        width: 500
                    });
                    jwplayer().play()
                    slider.startStop(false);
                    onComplete(function () { slider.startStop(true) })

                } else {
                    var vid = slider.$currentPage.find('video');
                    if (vid.length > 0) {
                        console.log(vid);
                        vid[0].play();
                    }

                }


            },
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I am beginning to think this is an IE9 and HTML5 video issue as I have isolated the video slide and put it on a notepad and created and HTML5 format page, ran it in IE9 and the video plays once, then if you hit the play button again it fails. Could this be CODEC?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it's a codec problem. Are you removing all of the `console.log()` when you run it? Or is the console open when you do?

Comment: in my distilled test on just a plain HTML5 formatted page running from my desktop I have no console.log implemented. After some testing of various videos and checking the codecs I can not determine anything. I have one video from 'video for everybody' which plays fine, codec is MPEG4 Base Media /Version 2. I have others which are MPEG4 Base Media, some play all the time, some break on the second run... I am stumpped